# Can not upload file into folder using PHP

Tags: php, file

I am trying to upload file into folder using PHP but it can not done. My code is below.

user.php:

```
$target_dir = "admin/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$uploadOk = 1;
$check = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
header('Content-Type: application/json');  
if ($check !== false) {  

  $uploadOk = 1;
} else {  

  $uploadOk = 0;
}

if (file_exists($target_file)) {  
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
            if ($uploadOk == 0) {  
            } else {
              if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {  
                $result['msg'] = "Image has uploaded successfully.";
                $result['num'] = 1;
                $result['img'] =$_FILES['file']['name'];
              } else {
                $result['msg'] = "Sorry, Your Image could not uploaded to the directory.";
                $result['num'] = 0;
   }

}
```

I am getting the message `Sorry, Your Image could not uploaded to the directory.`. Here I am getting the input for `$_FILES` is like below.

```
$_FILES=array('file'=>array('name' => 'IMG-20161121-WA0000.jpg','type' => ' application/octet-stream','tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpSb6a53', 'error' => 0, 'size' => 119198));
```

I have also the folder write permission.My directory structure is like below.

```
root folder

    ->admin
       =>uploads//(images need to saved)


    -> API
        =>V1
           ->user.php(//here is my file upload code)
```

In this case always I am unable to upload the files into folder.

Comment: may be your directory don't have read-write permission. change the folder permission to 077

Comment: Check you permissions for the directory.

Comment: what does the php error_log say?  The directory will not only need to be writeable, but also owned by the same user that the webserver runs as (eg apache/nginx) - assuming this is a linux server?

Comment: I have the folder permission.

Comment: @flauntster : Yes,this is ubuntu server.

Comment: @Anant : Actually this `$_FILES` input is accepting from mobile device .For webpage fileinput this code is working fine and upload the image into folder.But here i am making one webservice which will accept the file from mobile device and saved into folder.so in this case there is only problem.

Comment: @satya, what `Content-type` header used by mobile device ? They should use `Form-Data`

Comment: @Karan : its `multipart/form-data` used in mobile side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$targetdir` to:

`$targetdir = '../../admin/uploads';`

Answer (score 0):

Your upload directory is relative to path of your script. You can change it with this:

```
$target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/admin/uploads/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$target_dir = __DIR__ . "/admin/uploads/";
```